Navigator doesn't pop after login in Flutter
I have a CircularProgressIndicator while logging in in my flutter app, yet the indicator doesn't pop after redirection and the user needs to pop the context manually.
SquareTile(                      
                         onTap: () async {
  // Show the progress indicator
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: true,
    builder: (context) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  );

  try {
    // Sign in with Google
    await AuthService().signInWithGoogle();
    
    // Check if the user is authenticated
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User? user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      // If authenticated, navigate to MyHomePage
          // Dismiss the progress indicator
          if(mounted){
    await Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
          }
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyHomePage()),
      );
    }

After the user gets to MyHomePage the indicator sometimes is showing and sometimes isn't, how can I fix this?

You should use the Navigator.of(context).pop() method.
There is a slight difference between them, head on the link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/maybePop.html
